# How to require at least N assertions to be run in NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

With QUnit I can [explicitly `expect`](https://api.qunitjs.com/expect/) that a specific number of assertions will be run in my test (heck, by default at least 1 assertion is expected anyways, or the test fails).

Is there any way to do something similar with NUnit? (Heck, by default tests without assertions even pass...).

To clarify, here's an example / repro. Suppose I'm test-driving this code:

```
public class Util
{
    public static void MyMethod(Action someAction)
    {
        // We're TDD'ing, and we are *just about* to write:
        //someAction();
    }
}
```

then before I write that `someAction();` call I want to write a test. Here's the test I *want* to write:

```
[Test]
public void MyMethod_WhenGivenAction_ShouldCallAction()
{
    Assert.Expect(1); // Pseudo code, but this doesn't work.
    Util.MyMethod(() => Assert.That(true));
}
```

Of course I can workaround with this:

```
[Test]
public void MyMethod_WhenGivenAction_ShouldCallAction()
{
    bool wasCalled = false;
    Util.MyMethod(() => wasCalled = true);
    Assert.That(wasCalled);
}
```

And I guess I could even write my own Extension method on `Assert` to do this in a single line, but I was wondering **if there's an idiomatic / built in way to "expect N assertions" with NUnit?**

Comment: PS. I've [cross-posted something similar to the news group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/D18m1SwOehE) (TLDR version is to stick with the "workaround" I already mention).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, for some context (as this question seems to be mainly about "`N=1`" (i.e. expecting at least one assertion in each test)) one of the NUnit authors gives some insights about that [on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/D18m1SwOehE):

> We once considered requiring an assertion in each test, failing it
>   otherwise. We also considered giving an Inconclusive result in such a
>   case. Both ran afoul of a fairly common usage where folks simply make
>   a call, verifying that no exception is thrown. I don't like such tests
>   myself but since some people use them we felt they had to be
>   supported.

Earlier in that same thread it also becomes clear that it is intentional that NUnit users have no access to the number of assertions that were run. Some of the reasoning given:

> Generally, we don't think your test should know anything about the
>   test infrastructure. NUnit's count of asserts is something private to
>   NUnit, until it is tallied up for the final result of the test. It may
>   include asserts executed in setup, by the test itself or even in
>   teardown - though that's not recommended. It may include asserts
>   executed by ActionAttributes placed on the test, the fixture or on a
>   higher level suite. For your test to know how many asserts will be
>   executed, it has to know pretty much everything about the environment
>   in which it is being run. That defeats the whole idea of test
>   independence.

In short, it's just not possible. Either use one of the other answers given by @ФагимСадыков, or follow this advice from the Google Group:

> The "workaround" you show is pretty much the normal way of checking
>   that a callback was called in NUnit, xUnit, mbUnit and mstest

That is, this type of test:

```
[Test]
public void MyMethod_WhenGivenAction_ShouldCallAction()
{
    bool wasCalled = false;
    Util.MyMethod(() => wasCalled = true);
    Assert.That(wasCalled);
}
```

Bottom line: checking the (or expecting a) number of assertions run is not possible in NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Where's no builtin facility for.
Suggest to implement your own.

If you just want it once, it could be something like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class myfixture {
    [Test]
    public void MyAssertCheckTest(){ // this test will fail if all other test fails
        var mytests = new Action[]{Test1,Test2};
        int failcount = mytests.Length;
        foreach(var test in mytests){
            try{
                test();
            }catch{
                if(--failcount==-1){
                    Assert.Fail("too many fails");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit] //mark it explicit - we want to check it only if MyAssertCheckTest fails
    public void Test1(){
        Assert.True(false);
    }

    [Test]
    [Explicit]
    public void Test2(){
        Assert.True(true);
    }   
}
```

This sample shown one of reasones not to have such things in NUnit - it's not much clear semantic (why we allow something to fail?)

If you want to have it as usual facility the best i think is to use `[Suite]` instead of `[TestFixture]` and implement own caller of underlined tests.

Or make own `MyAsserts.AtLeast(int failcount, params Action[] subtests)` or something similar.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but even for a workaround this is too hackish for my taste. This has all sorts of weird side effects (e.g. this will muck up the Test Explorer and readability of test results in general, and it will negate NUnit's features around isolating tests) that heavily outweigh the original symptom.

Comment: By the way, re-reading the answer it's unclear to me how I'd use this code to expect N assertions within a specific test?

Comment: I think NUnit Assert design and mean is not exactly match your expectations. And I think that you will agree that QUnit's ideology is quite exotic (i don't mean that it's bad, but excotic) - because Assert means by it's semantic that something Should BE or It's Error otherwise. Test failure means that something bad. I don't understand QUnit feature in TDD - why something can go wrong and don't disturb me? So try to lie to NUnit and try to show it failed tests/assertions as not failed - will be hackish, while it's really hack ))))))

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow your last comment (some language issue may be part of this), but in any case I do *not* think "QUnit's ideology is quite exotic". On the contrary, I think QUnit nicely fits in the xUnit-family of testing frameworks, and in many ways is very similar to NUnit.

Comment: Also, restating my second comment a bit: I appreciate the effort, but I fail to see how the code in this answer could be used to assert that a certain number of assertions have taken place. The code is *way* different from the context / code I gave in my question...

Comment: Will add another answer

Answer (score 0):

By discussion under previous answer.
Assert is not class that is usefull for your scenario. Make your own class if you really want to
If using Assert.

```
var failcount = 3;
try{
   Assert.AreEqual(false,true);
}catch(AssertException e){
   if((--failcount)==-1){
     throw e;
   }
}
```

I think it's very ugly. Assert ALWAYS throw errors so if you want to make it clear do it somehow else.

So you can rewrite NUnit and add posibility to do so and make pool request, and if not, it still required to be written

As variant:
1) write own Assert for ex QAssert that optionally get QContext where FailCount defined, it can be wrapper for Assert

```
public static QAssert {
public static bool AreEqual ( object a, object b, QContext context ) { //while it's not fail sometimes while it's not AreEqual it should return bool
    if(null==context || context.FailAvailable<=0) {
        Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
        return true;
    }
    try{
        Assert.AreEqual(a,b);
        return true;
    }catch(AssertExceptio e){
        context.FailAvailable--;
        context.FailedTests.Add(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

Then in your test

```
[Test]
public void MultiFail(){
var context = new QContext{AvailFail=2};
QAssert.False(true, context); //AvailFail=1
QAssert.True(false, context); //AvailFail=2
QAssert.True(true, context);
}
```

Test will be passed

If you realy want to make it cool, you can make your own magic with Attributes, StackTrace and teach your QAssert automatically initialize QContext and use it:

```
[Test]
[QContext(AvailFail=2)]
public void MultiFail(){
QAssert.False(true); //AvailFail=1
QAssert.True(false); //AvailFail=2
QAssert.True(true);
}
```

It really can be accomplished with internal static `Dictionary<MethodInfo,QContext>`, `QContextAttribute` and with `StackTrace.GetFrame(...)` - if explicit QContext is null QAssert's lookup StackTrace and find closest method with Test attribute, then it looks at dictionary - if no dictionary still (first assert in test) - it initialize it using QContextAttribute (if attached to method) - then it use it, all following QAssert calls will use cached dictionary.
It's very simple implementation -it not free cached dict, so if one test will be called twice it will reuse context that is not much qood, but for most cases this schema could work.